# Создать json из данных таблицы postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Предположим у меня есть такая таблица в PostgreSQL:

```
 id |   nickname   |    name
----+--------------+-----------
  1 |     some     |    Alex
  2 |   nickname   |     Po
  3 |     here     |    BoB
  4 |  for example |    Rich
```

Мне нужно с помощью `select` команды получить такой результат:

```
{"id": [1, 2, 3, 4], "nickname": ["some", "nickname", "here", "for example"], "name": ["Alex", "Po", "BoB", "Rich"]}
```

Это возможно? Не смог найти ничего похожего

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html - `json_agg`, попробуйте

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n Пробовал, пока что более менее внятное получилось сделать только с помощью ```select json_agg(json_build_object('id', id, 'nickname', nickname)) ...```, но все еще не то

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
select json_build_object(
   'id', array_agg(id order by id),
   'nickname', array_agg(nickname order by id),
   'name', array_agg(name order by id))
from tbl
```